# Problemas con las etiquetas "div"

Tags: html

[image: A la izquierda, el problema.]

Hola comunidad. Estoy creando un portafolio con HTML en Visual Studio Code y estoy teniendo problemas con los div. Cuando coloco algún elemento, como una imagen un video o cualquier otra cosa, no se coloca en toda la longitud. Aunque en los estilos de CSS la longitud al 100%, de esta manera: `ejemplo {width : 100%}` no funciona. Por favor, ¿alguien sabe como arreglar este problema?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], el código debe ir como texto, considera proveer un [mcve]

Comment: vscode es una ide.. el problema no lo tenes con vs code.. lo tenes con tu html.. que es lo que tenemos que mirar... da lo mismo en que lo programes...

Comment: No entiendo qué problema tienes...podrías publicar código y a qué quieres llegar?

Comment: En realidad tiene más que ver con la hoja de estilos, no con el HTML. En definitiva, falta información